# Using SQL CASE statement to compare dates and do multiplication

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to output the art name, price, and a new price.  The new price is based off the date the piece of art was acquired.  if it was before 2010 than it is an increase of 10%, if it was in 2010 it is an increase of 5%.  I'm using a case statement but can't seem to get past where i am at.  I keep getting an ORA-00905 missing keyword error at line 3.

```
SELECT artname, price, newprice,
CASE Price
WHEN DtAcquired < '01-JAN-2010' THEN TRUC(price*1.10, 2)
ELSE TRUNC(price*1.05, 2)
END AS newprice
FROM Arts;
```

Any idea of what i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend writing this as:

```
SELECT artname, price,
       TRUNC(CASE WHEN DtAcquired < DATE '2010-01-01' THEN price*1.10 ELSE price*1.05
              END, 2) as newprice
FROM Arts;
```

A few notes:

- The problem is mixing the two types of `case` expression.  Just use the `when <condition>` form.
- No need to have `newprice` twice in the `SELECT`.
- I don't recommend having the `TRUNC()` logic twice.  For consistency, make the `case` an argument to `trunc()`.

Comment: This solved the problem and in a much more effective way than i was attempting.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use CASE price AND WHEN with condtion but  have a case directly on WHEN in this case eg:

```
SELECT artname, price, 
CASE 
    WHEN DtAcquired < '01-JAN-2010' 
          THEN TRUNC(price*1.10, 2)
          ELSE TRUNC(price*1.05, 2)
END AS newprice
FROM Arts;
```

Comment: I tried entering it like that before, but when i do i get an error on line 1: ORA-00904: "NEWPRICE": Invalid identifier.   I was able to get rid of the error by using CASE Price.  Not that it was correct but it did get rid of the error.